# How do I send data to a Racket server?

Tags: webserver, lisp, racket

Modifying an [online example](https://www.monolune.com/simple-web-applications-in-racket/) I have the following code which allows a http request to be made to this Racket webserver;

```
#lang racket

(require web-server/servlet) 
(require web-server/servlet-env)

(define (http-response content)  
  (response/full
    200                  ; HTTP response code.
    #"OK"                ; HTTP response message.
    (current-seconds)    ; Timestamp.
    TEXT/HTML-MIME-TYPE  ; MIME type for content.
    '()                  ; Additional HTTP headers.
    (list                ; Content (in bytes) to send to the browser.
      (string->bytes/utf-8 content))))

(define (show-time-page request)
  (http-response (number->string (current-seconds))))

(define (greeting-page request)  
  (http-response (list-ref '("Hi" "Hello") (random 2))))

 (define get-data ...)

;; URL routing table (URL dispatcher).
(define-values (dispatch generate-url)
  (dispatch-rules
    [("time") show-time-page]
    [("hello") greeting-page]  ; Notice this line.
    [else (error "There is no procedure to handle the url.")]))

(define (request-handler request)
  (dispatch request))

;; Start the server.
(serve/servlet
  request-handler
  #:launch-browser? #f
  #:quit? #f
  #:listen-ip "127.0.0.1"
  #:port 8001
  #:servlet-regexp #rx"")
```

How do I change the above code to allow it to receive data (such as a string) posted to the Racket webserver via a http-request and display it in the console? Please can you help?

Comment: Have you looked at [the extended example in the manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html) and the [reference manual on web applications](https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/index.html)?

Answer (score 4):

Define a request handler for the `POST` request. Have it extract the posted data from the `request`:

```
(define (example-post request)
  (define data (request-post-data/raw request))
  (define str (format "got post data: ~v" data))
  (displayln str)
  (http-response str))
```

Add the handler to `dispatch-rules`. Be sure to specify it's handling a `POST` (not the default `GET`) request:

```
;; URL routing table (URL dispatcher).
(define-values (dispatch generate-url)
  (dispatch-rules
    [("time") show-time-page]
    [("hello") greeting-page]
    [("example-post") #:method "post" example-post] ; <=== NEW
    [else (error "There is no procedure to handle the url.")]))
```

Now, in a shell if you do

```
curl --data "hi" http://127.0.0.1:8001/example-post
```

it will show the response data `got post data: #"hi"` --- as will the Racket console.